# Add dependency between two systemd services to start again if one of them is killed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, service, ubuntu-18.04, systemd

I have two systemd services A.service and B.service in /etc/systemd/system/ directory.

**Below is the configuration in A.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=A Service

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s
ExecStart=/opt/myapp/A_service.sh -a start
ExecStop=/opt/myapp/A_service.sh -a stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Below is the configuration in B.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=B Service
After=A.service
BindsTo=A.service

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s
ExecStart=/opt/myapp/B_service.sh -a start
ExecStop=/opt/myapp/B_service.sh -a stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I want to create a dependency such that when A.service gets restarted B.service should also get restarted.

But it's not working when i kill **A.service** with `sudo kill -9 <A.service pid>`.
I can see **A.service** getting restarted after kill but **B.service** is in stopped state, not getting restarted.

Can someone help me configure this dependency?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `PartOf` dependency.

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#PartOf=

> PartOf=
>
> Configures dependencies similar to Requires=, but limited to stopping and restarting of units. When systemd stops or restarts the units listed here, the action is propagated to this unit. Note that this is a one-way dependency — changes to this unit do not affect the listed units.
> When PartOf=b.service is used on a.service, this dependency will show as ConsistsOf=a.service in property listing of b.service. ConsistsOf= dependency cannot be specified directly.

```
Description=B Service
After=A.service
BindsTo=A.service
PartOf=A.service

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s
ExecStart=/opt/myapp/B_service.sh -a start
ExecStop=/opt/myapp/B_service.sh -a stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```